# TFS 2008: Permissions messed up on source control folder

Tags: security, tfs, permissions

I have a folder structure in TFS 2008 like this:

$/[Project Collection]/Project/

```
     >> /MainBranch/ApplicationCode

     >> /DevelopmentBranch/ApplicationCode
```

I right clicked on the "MainBranch/ApplicationCode" folder in Source Control Explorer from with VS2010 and clicked "Properties" and the "Security" tab.  I got the error "The access control list for the item $/[Project Collection]/Project/MainBranch/ApplicationCode could not be retrieved.  The item may not exist on the server, or you do not have permission to access it".  Another guy on my team gets the same error and he is in the "TFS Administrators" group.  I think the Service Account permission got unset on the "ApplicationCode" folder, but I can't be sure.

My question is: Is there a way to reset the permissions on a folder when the "Service Account" lost permissions?

It is my understanding that when you do this through Visual Studio (or any other gui or cmd line interface), the "Service Account" is the proxy on the TFS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Engineer ran "tf permission" command on that folder and found that the "Inherit Permissions" on that folder was set to "false".  He set it back to "True" and the folder reappeared in the Source Control Explorer.

Edit:  This was done on the local TFS server.